# Vimwiki overriding normal md highlighting

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

I love the concept of Vimwiki, but have a problem with it overriding the default md syntax highlighting. The default works well, and I use it regularly to edit md documents to be used with pandoc. Vimwiki changes this highlighting even in non-wiki md files, making my documents much harder to read.

Is there a way to use the default syntax highlighting for markdown files, while still being able to use Vimwiki? I tried reading the manual, but have found no such option yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your vim configuration. Not everything, just the parts related to vimwiki.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but you can try the following. Append it to your vimrc.

```
let g:vimwiki_ext2syntax = {}
```

Let me know the result.